# Proof of Possession for JWT

Tags: jwt, bearer-token, apigee, http-method

I came across some reading around the concept of Proof of Possession(PoP) in case of JWT. I wanted to know if we have any sample APIs implemented around this.

Comment: The JWT needs to be validated again a cert endpoint whic proves that a valid  jwt Has been obtained

Comment: do you have any sample APIs implemented for reference in GitLab or anywhere

Comment: I use https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client. The validation is done by Token Verifier https://github.com/googleapis/google-oauth-java-client/blob/master/google-oauth-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/auth/openidconnect/IdTokenVerifier.java